# Update MongoDb collection and not rewrite it

Tags: mongodb, nosql, robo3t

I have a collection with the following objects:

```js
{ 
  ...
  "address": {
    "addressLine1": "some address"
    "city": "some city"
  }
}
```

I need to update all objects to add `address.fullName = address.addressLine1` (don't ask why :D) in cases when `address` exist.

I try to run this script in Robo 3T:

```js
db.getCollection('suppliers').updateMany(
    // query 
    {},
    
    // update 
    { $set: { address: { fullName: $address.address1 } }  },
    
    // options 
    {
        // update only one document
        "multi" : true,
        // insert a new document, if no existing document match the query
        "upsert" : false 
    }
);
```

I have an error

> "$address isn't defined"

How should I write a script

1. To update `address.fullName = address.addressLine1`
2. Don't rewrite an entire object and subObject address (important)

Answer (score 2):

Following this [example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#example-1) from the MongoDB documentation, your update should be wrapped in an array like this.

```js
db.getCollection('suppliers').updateMany(
  {},
  [
    {
      $set: {
        'address.fullName': '$address.addressLine1',
      },
    },
  ],
  {
    multi: false,
    upsert: false,
  }
);
```

See a working example on [MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QBD1lFJtCu6)

Comment: You're welcome. Consider accepting the answer as well. @NikitaPolevoy